# Fresh RVM Installation on OS X, not able to run server due to sqlite3 issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, rvm

I installed rvm on my Mac OS X 10.6.8 (running Snow Leopard) and tried to start up my first sample app. After a few hours of fiddling around with the gems, I decided to post the issue here, because I really don't know how to figure this out:

Whenever I try to run the dev-server in my app-folder, I get the following error:

```
/Users/santeri/RubymineProjects/sample_app/script/rails server -b 0.0.0.0 -p 3000 -e     development
/Users/santeri/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.7/lib/sqlite3.rb:6:in `require':      dlopen(/Users/santeri/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.7/lib/sqlite3/sqlite3_native.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libsqlite3.0.8.6.dylib (LoadError)
Referenced from: /Users/santeri/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.7/lib/sqlite3/sqlite3_native.bundle
    Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
        /usr/local/lib/libsqlite3.0.8.6.dylib: mach-o, but wrong architecture
        /usr/local/lib/libsqlite3.0.8.6.dylib: mach-o, but wrong architecture - /Users/santeri/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.7/lib/sqlite3/sqlite3_native.bundle
```

I only have 1 ruby version installed inside my rvm:

```
/Users/santeri/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bin/ruby
```

Running **'lipo -info /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib'** returns:

Architectures in the fat file: /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib are: x86_64 i386 ppc7400

Thanks for any help or hint!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I **strongly** recommend you install SQLite through **[Homebrew](http://mxcl.github.io/homebrew/)**

1. Install Homebrew by running the following in your terminal and following the prompts and instructions

   ```
   ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/mxcl/homebrew/go)"
   ```
2. Run `brew install sqlite`
3. Restart your rails server

This should solve your problems. This will give Rails an architecture-correct `.dylib` file to work with, located in a directory like `/usr/local/Cellar/sqlite/3.7.15.1/lib/` instead of `/usr/local/bin`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I've actually installed sqlite with homebrew. It is located in the directory you posted. /usr/local/Cellar/.../lib/. What could be the issue? Maybe I need to symlink?

Comment: Running `brew unlink sqlite && brew link sqlite` will re-link the package.

Comment: Doing so results in: `This formula is keg-only: so it was not symlinked into /usr/local` and `Error: Could not symlink file: /usr/local/Cellar/sqlite/3.7.16.2/bin/sqlite3
Target /usr/local/bin/sqlite3 already exists. You may need to delete it.`